# What is the meaning of prime notation in surveys' calibration estimators?

Tags: survey, estimators, methodology, calibration

I am reading about survey methodologies and my question is about the meaning of prime notation as you can see in the picture below[image]

For a second example please check the link to the [paper](https://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/Proceedings/papers/1997_011.pdf) where I found the prime notation mentioned many times.

Does it mean the transpose of a matrix in this paper?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without more context it is hard to say for sure but that is a common notation.

Comment: Thanks for you comment mdewey :)
For the link I provided can you check the page 2 of the paper please? the context there is more clear

Comment: for the full text shown in the picture please check this link: home.lu.lv/~pm90015/.../W2012_CP_WANG_LISHA.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably the transpose operator on the vector $x_k$ where $k$ is a unit. You see $x_k$ written out as a row vector but the author wants to tell you that it's actually a column vector.